# Не работает streamwrapper zip

Tags: php, streamwrapper, zip

Вот это возращает содержимое файла

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('file:///tmp/arhive_test/arhive_test.zip'));
```

А это выдает ошибку **failed to open stream: operation failed**

```
file_get_contents('zip:///tmp/arhive_test/arhive_test.zip');
```

Так тоже не работает

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('zip://file:///tmp/arhive_test/arhive_test.zip'));
```

Врапер установлен

```
php > print_r(stream_get_wrappers());
Array
(
    [0] => https
    [1] => ftps
    [2] => compress.zlib
    [3] => compress.bzip2
    [4] => php
    [5] => file
    [6] => glob
    [7] => data
    [8] => http
    [9] => ftp
    [10] => phar
    [11] => zip
)
```

Вот так работает

```
$za = new ZipArchive();
php > $za->open('/tmp/arhive_test/arhive_test.zip');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ оказался простой, этот wrapper получает stream только на обьект в архиве а не на сам архив.

Так не правильно

```
file_get_contents('zip:///tmp/arhive_test/arhive_test.zip')
```

Так правильно

```
file_get_contents('zip:///tmp/arhive_test/arhive_test.zip#doc1.txt')
```